# WebImageSearch for images of high resolution?

Tags: image, web-access, webservices

Is there a way to specify a minimal image dimension when using `WebImageSearch`? Since it costs money I don't want to do a large search and then filter the results.
Something like this would be nice if it existed:

```
WebImageSearch["tiger", "Images", MaxItems -> 1, 
 MinimumResolution -> 500]
```

Perhaps there is some undocumented method of achieving this?

Comment: Doesn't look like [Bing Image Search](https://dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/8336afba49a84475ba401758c0dbf749/operations/56b4433fcf5ff8098cef380c) supports this so probably no way to do it. Maybe going through Google?